# Install extension in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add https://github.com/adjust/pg-numhstore extension to my postgres.

when i run the command:

CREATE EXTENSION numhstore

I get no control file found.

I added the control file in /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension from the repository link given above.

I get error as extension "numhstore" has no installation script nor update path for version.

pg_config result:

```
BINDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-12
HTMLDIR = /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-12
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/postgresql
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/include/postgresql/12/server
LIBDIR = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib
LOCALEDIR = /usr/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/share/postgresql/12/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/share/postgresql/12
SYSCONFDIR = /etc/postgresql-common
PGXS = /usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-icu' '--with-tcl' '--with-perl' '--with-python' '--with-pam' '--with-openssl' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' 'PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3' '--mandir=/usr/share/postgresql/12/man' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-12' '--sysconfdir=/etc/postgresql-common' '--datarootdir=/usr/share/' '--datadir=/usr/share/postgresql/12' '--bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/postgresql/' '--includedir=/usr/include/postgresql/' '--with-extra-version= (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)' '--enable-nls' '--enable-integer-datetimes' '--enable-thread-safety' '--enable-tap-tests' '--enable-debug' '--enable-dtrace' '--disable-rpath' '--with-uuid=e2fs' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-pgport=5432' '--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo' '--with-llvm' 'LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-6.0' 'CLANG=/usr/bin/clang-6.0' '--with-systemd' '--with-selinux' 'MKDIR_P=/bin/mkdir -p' 'TAR=/bin/tar' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' '--with-gssapi' '--with-ldap' '--with-includes=/usr/include/mit-krb5' '--with-libs=/usr/lib/mit-krb5' '--with-libs=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer
CFLAGS_SL = -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,--as-needed
LDFLAGS_EX = 
LDFLAGS_SL = 
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lpthread -lselinux -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -ledit -lrt -lcrypt -ldl -lm 
VERSION = PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Comment: The control file isn't enough. You need to compile the source code to get the binaries (`.so`)  and they need to be copied to the `/usr/share/postgresql/11/lib`

Comment: Can you please state the complete steps?

Comment: What are the steps to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to compile PostgreSQL source code are documented here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/install-short.html

Once this is done you need to install extension source code, compile it using the PostgreSQL environment you have just built. Using the extension Makefile you likely need to run:

```
make
make install
```

Unfortunately this extension has no installation documentation and is not referenced in PGXN which makes it more difficult to install it.

Comment: on running i am getting errors: make install

In file included from src/hstore_array.h:4:0,
                 from src/hstore_array.c:1:
src/pg_numhstore.h:4:10: fatal error: postgres.h: No such file or directory
 #include "postgres.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'src/hstore_array.o' failed
make: *** [src/hstore_array.o] Error 1

Comment: Did you first install and compile PostgreSQL ? What is the output of `pg_config` ?

Comment: I did configure: error: readline library not found
If you have readline already installed, see config.log for details on the
failure.  It is possible the compiler isn't looking in the proper directory.
Use --without-readline to disable readline support.

Comment: You need to have an error free PostgreSQL installation from source code: if a package is missing you need to install it, if there is another error you need to fix it. This is really needed to install an extension that is using directly C code from PostgreSQL internal routines.

Comment: Ok i have added the required dependencies and i edited my question and it contains pg_config result. Now can i clone and run the make install anywhere for numhstore or would it be at specific location?

Comment: I am not sure: the output of `pg_config` should match the input of your specific`./configure` step: the displayed output looks like the standard one from a binary installation of PostgreSQL. In your configure step you should have chosen a specific target installation directory with `--prefix`: I don't see it. If you have done this you should update PATH so that this installation from source is chosen and the right pg_config is run.